# bind properties of user control the properties of the parent user control wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a UserControl "UsersGrid" with one gridview and some other objects inside.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainMenu.Views.UsersGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ToggleSwitch="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch;assembly=ToggleSwitch"
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  
             mc:Ignorable="ignore d"
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="250"
             DataContext="{Binding UsersGrid, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             >
    <UserControl.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="d:/images.jpg"/>
    </UserControl.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="3 3 3 3"
                   x:Name="panel_useri">
            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                        Margin="2">
                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                           FontFamily="Times New Roman" 
                           FontSize="16" 
                           FontWeight="Bold" 
                           Content="Utilizatori" 
                           Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                </Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Right" >
                    <Label Content="Activi" 
                           FontSize="14" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                           FontWeight="DemiBold" 
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                           Padding="5,0" 
                           Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    <ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch
                        IsChecked="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="0,0,0,2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid_users"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                FilteringMode="FilterRow"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                ShowGroupPanel="False"
                IsBusy="{Binding IsGridUsersBusy}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding GridUsersTable}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1},Path=SelectedGridUsersRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
                >
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Nume"
                                                HeaderTextAlignment="Center"
                                                Width="1*"
                                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding NumeUser}" />
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The second user control is parent of "UsersGrid" and have aloso other object...

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainMenu.Views.Test"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MainMenu.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="700"
         DataContext="{Binding Test, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:UsersGrid x:Name="oUsers" Grid.Column="0"  />

    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="here some value of item selected from gridview" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>


</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel of second UC:

```
namespace MainMenu.ViewModel {
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase  {

    public TestViewModel() {
    }
    private GridUsers_row _selectedGridUsersRow;
    public GridUsers_row SelectedGridUsersRow
    {
        get { return _selectedGridUsersRow; }
        set
        {
            _selectedGridUsersRow = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedGridUsersRow");
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I bind SelectedItem from "telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid_users"" to "SelectedGridUsersRow" from ViewModel of second U.C. ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have one DataContext item which contains both the collection of items for the grid data, and the Selected Item.

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase  
{
    public TestViewModel() { }

    private ObservableCollection<User> _users;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set
        {
            _users= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }

    private User _selectedUser;
    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get { return _selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            _selectedUser= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
        }
    }
}
```

Your XAML would look roughly like this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainMenu.Views.Test" ...
             DataContext="{Binding MyTestViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid>
        ...

        <local:UsersGrid x:Name="oUsers" Grid.Column="0" />

        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedUser.Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<!-- Note that DataContext is NOT set here. Because it is not set,
<!--- it will use DataContext from parent item, which is TestViewModel -->
<UserControl x:Class="MainMenu.Views.UsersGrid" ...>
    ...

    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid_users"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
                    ...>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

First UserControl has allredy a ViewModel:

```
namespace MainMenu.ViewModel {
public class UsersGridViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public UsersGridViewModel() {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init() {
        using (var conn = new FbConnection(Config.connString)) {

            //populate users grid
            IEnumerable<GridUsers_row> c_useri = conn.Query(@"select aa.id, aa.nume, aa.dela 
                                                            from useri aa 
                                                            where aa.deleted=0 and aa.dela is not null
                                                            order by aa.nume")
                                                 .Select(row => new GridUsers_row() {
                                                     IdUser = row.ID,
                                                     NumeUser = row.NUME,
                                                     ldDela = row.DELA.ToString(),
                                                 });
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                GridUsersTable.Clear();
                GridUsersTable.AddRange(c_useri);
            });

        }
    }

    //c_useri
    private ObservableRangeCollection<GridUsers_row> _gridUsers = new ObservableRangeCollection<GridUsers_row>();
    public ObservableRangeCollection<GridUsers_row> GridUsersTable
    {
        get { return _gridUsers; }
        set
        {
            if (_gridUsers == value)
                return;
            _gridUsers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("GridUsersTable");
        }
    }
}
}
```

The proposed solution would work if my both u.c. had a single DataContent and I do not want that...